# Using explode to add contents to existing array

Tags: php

I have this statement inside a loop.

```
$chosenUrls = explode ( ',' , $connect[$i]['url'] );
```

Is there anyway to get it to add to the $chosenUrls array, rather than replacing what's in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have $chosenUrls[] = explode ( ',' , $connect[$i]['url'] ) to add new url in your array in every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$chosenUrls=array();

 for(...)
{
  array_push($chosenUrls,explode ( ',' , $connect[$i]['url'] ));
}
```

Comment: What do I put in the for loop? Can't figure out why it doesn't work without it though. Shouldn't it just push everything down already there?

Comment: `array_merge` might be a better option than `array_push`, depending on the desired result.

Comment: well in the loop you should iterate your array of ? urls? As you have written -> $connect[$i]['url']= url,url,url

Comment: `array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'http://www.vcricket.com/' (length=24)
      1 => string 'http://www.surreycricket.com/' (length=29)`

Comment: Alex don't think I can do that as that changes on each loop.

Comment: wait something is weird, you said that this "$chosenUrls = explode ( ',' , $connect[$i]['url'] );" is called in each loop iteration. And you want the data to be appended...wright ? or have I misunderstud something...

Answer (score 1):

Your current code tells it to replace `$chosenUrls` every time. You need to modify it:

```
for(...){

 $chosenUrls[] = explode ( ',' , $connect[$i]['url'] );

}
```

Note the `[]` after `$chosenUrls`. This will push a new element into `$chosenUrls` on each iteration.